# How do I change the background of an Android tab widget?

Tags: android, widget, tabs

My class extends extends TabActivity

```
TabHost mTabHost =  getTabHost();

TabHost.TabSpec tab1 =mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
TabHost.TabSpec tab2 =mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");

tab1 .setIndicator("title tab1");
tab2 .setIndicator("title tab2");
mTabHost.addTab(tab1);mTabHost.addTab(tab2);

TabHost.setCurrentTab(0 or 1)
```

Can anybody guide me how do I change the background image or color of selected tab?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What if you register for TabHost.OnTabChanged events and call mTabHost.getCurrentTabView() to get the View, then view.setBackgroundResource()?

Answer (score 91):

This will set your tab colors:

```
public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
    for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) {
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); //unselected
    }
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF")); // selected
}
```

and if you put it within the onTabChangedListener(), it will keep the correct color for selected tabs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me. Is there any way to implement this approach in XML?

Comment: @teoREtik XML is static content, only for when your activity is first launched (layout initialisation), so no.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. This answer is very helpful.. +1 for that.. Cheers up..!!

Comment: What abought highlighting on touch?

Comment: I don't like this way. but i don't think we have better way

Comment: helpful! Take +1..But I do wanna more stylish tab e.g http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ ..It give .xml and .png..How do I implement this? And can it compatible for android 2.2? I intend my app for almost android version..Give me some tutorials..

Comment: If you want to use an XML file you can check out the answer below that sets the selector in an XML style http://stackoverflow.com/a/7453721/413127

Answer (score 36):

As mbaird mentioned, the better solution is to use **background** with selector, so you don't have to check `onTabChanged` and do manual update. The minimal code is here:

```
private void initTabsAppearance(TabWidget tabWidget) {
    // Change background
    for(int i=0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++)
        tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg);
}
```

Where `tab_bg` is an xml drawable with selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_normal" />
</selector>
```

For the full Tab customization I will add the code for changing **tab text style** using custom theme. Add this to `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/CustomTabWidget</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabWidget" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabWidgetText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabWidgetText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

To use this theme, define it in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme">
```

And now you have tab widgets with **custom background** and **custom text style**.

Answer (score 2):

Does [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/46c11c89fd7e3e17/e3c73b966fa4243b?lnk=raot) solve your problem?  Basically calling setBackgroundDrawable on each tab view with a selector?

Answer (score 2):

```
>     TabHost mTabHost =  getTabHost();
>     
>     TabHost.TabSpec tab1 =mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
>     TabHost.TabSpec tab2 =mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
>     
>     tab1.setIndicator("title tab1");
>     tab2.setIndicator("title tab2");
>     mTabHost.addTab(tab1) ;mTabHost.addTab(tab2);
>     
>     TabHost.setCurrentTab(0 or 1);


mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab1selector); 

mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab2selector);    

mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab3selector);    

mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab4selector);
```

Use **.setBackgroundResource** and tabNselector is an XML - *tabNselector.xml*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tabN"/>
   <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tabNsel"  />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the 'android:background' parameter in the TabWidget element of the XML to give the generic background of all the tabs.

Then I passed views inflated from another XML in the '.setIndicator' method.

```
 View v = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_widget, null);
    TextView label = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tabLabel);
    label.setText("Whatever");
 tab1 .setContent(v);
```

I feel that's a nicer way of doing this.