# Android TabWidget set background color error

Tags: android, view, styles, tabwidget

I have been trying to apply a style to my TabWidget.

I've tried several methods such as

> for(int i=0;i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)               tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7392B5"));

from
[How do I change the background of an Android tab widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099959/how-do-i-change-the-background-of-an-android-tab-widget)

However, this code does not work for me. I've also tried messing with some XML styles. The closest I have gotten is to set the Divider, however that makes the entire tab widget turn one solid color and the Tabs are no longer drawn on top.

Please help. Mark's books only touch on setting the Icons for the tabs, not changing the color. I feel this should be simple, but TabWidgets and Hosts make everything harder.

I've tried this code targeting both the 1.6 and 2.2 platforms, but neither API works.

Thanks

Comment: I do it in the XML layout rather than in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background of a tab is actually a [NinePatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html) image, set into a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html). When you call `setBackgroundColor()`, you're replacing the set StateListDrawable with a simple color, so the entire tab turns into that color. What you'll need to do is actually modify (or draw your own) NinePatch tab images that are the color and style that you want for each state (e.g. focused, pressed, etc.).

Alternately, in code you could set a ColorFilter as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color/3485854#3485854) (`getBackground()` will work for a TabWidget as well as a button) but I'd recommend going the NinePatch route personally.