# Change color into TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a problem with my TabHost, I can not change the color. Here is my code:

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, DosageActivity.class);
spec = tabHost
        .newTabSpec("")
        .setIndicator("Dosages",
             res.getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_manage))
        .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

I tried several solutions written on the site but I can not do it and I'd keep the same code.
Thank you in advance

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356546/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-selected-tab-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Override `onTabChanged()` and then get `mTabHost.getCurrentTabView()` and just set the `BackgroundResource` for the view as `view.setBackgroundResource()`. For more you can check [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099959/how-do-i-change-the-background-of-an-android-tab-widget) answer.