# Is it possible to change the color of selected Tab in android?

Tags: android, colors, tabs

Hi i have two tabs in my tab widget,i want to apply the two different color for two tabs.am searching everywhere,mostly all colors are same while applying the tab.

**update**

**first tab** when selected red color

**second tab** when selected blue color

Here my code

```
tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    TabSpec firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");//these are color red
    TabSpec secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");//these color blue
    firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Sales Info",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sales));
    Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, a.class);
    firstTabSpec.setContent(photosIntent);
    secondTabSpec.setIndicator("Service Info",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.services));
    Intent photosIntent1 = new Intent(this, b.class);
    secondTabSpec.setContent(photosIntent1);
    tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
...onCreate(){

     ...
     tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {

        setTabColor(tabHost);
    }
     });
     setTabColor(tabHost);
...
}

//Change The Backgournd Color of Tabs
public void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {

    for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(COLOR_CYAN); //unselected

    if(tabhost.getCurrentTab()==0)
           tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(COLOR_RED); //1st tab selected
    else
           tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(COLOR_BLUE); //2nd tab selected
}
```

Comment: Thank you hiral its working but i apply the color code Color.green(0xCFEB5D) instead of (color.GREEN).its not working why?

Comment: It should work because Color.GREEN is directly accessible.You can then use Color.parseColor("#color_code_of_green");

Answer (score 7):

You can set `Listener` for your `TabHost` using `setOnTabChangedListener` and change it dynamically,

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   // add your tabs here

   // set the First Tab as selected Tab.
  setSelectedTabColor();
}
```

Create a method that will set the `Selected` and `Unselected` color of `Tab`.

```
 private void setSelectedTabColor() {
        for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)  
        {  
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                                            .setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);  
        }  
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                                              .setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); 
    }
```

Then inside your `onTabChanged()` you can dynamically change the Background.

```
@Override  
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {  
        setSelectedTabColor(); 
    }
```

You can use the same for `selected` and `unselected` Tab, [`here`](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-%E2%80%93-change-tab-bar-background-image/) is the Blog for the same.

Comment: Thank you ,Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to View am getting error View view = myTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tab)
                                             .setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
this line

Comment: the unselected tab also cyan color

Comment: @micro I had added the link for the same, how you can manage the unselected tabs also.

Comment: @thank you lalit  its working but i apply the color code Color.green(0xCFEB5D) instead of (color.GREEN).its not working why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7933/discussion-between-micro-and-lalit-poptani)

Answer (score 2):

Use the setIndicator(View view) instead of setIndicator(CharSequence label, Drawable icon). The background setting of the view you'll pass (e.g. if you're inflating an xml the parent layout) should be a ColorStateList to handle the clicks.