# Possible to change some aspect of themes (color)

Tags: android, user-interface, themes

**My Question:** Is it possible to change only part of a standard theme of an Android app? Specifically, I'm asking about the color.

**My Situation:** I'm using the `Holo.Light.DarkActionBar` theme (but this question is more general than that theme itself. I really like the blue theme Android has, but I'm wondering if I can change the theme to be orange instead. Maybe I can illustrate...

[image: Something like this...]

Is this possible without re-writing the theme? I realize I probably can't change the notification bar colors, and that's ok. I'm only concerned about the theme for my app, not the system.

Comment: Nope, you'll have to use a custom theme as the graphics are specifically designed with those colors. However, there are online resources to help: [Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/), [Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

Comment: Woah! I love the Android Holo Colors website. That's awesome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it without creating a custom theme, but using [Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) and other tools from the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html), most of the work will be done for you.  Just select the color you want and the UI elements that you want styled and it will generate the resources you need for your project.

Comment: Hey frenziedherring, so I just created a custom theme using Android Holo Colors. I made the color orange (as you see in my image above) but it didn't change the color of the tabs. Do you know what would explain this behavior? Is this something Android Holo Colors supports?

Comment: Looks like it may not have the tab accent could in Android Holo Colors.  This might help you though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356546/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-selected-tab-in-android