# Cannot set background colors of tabs programmatically in android

Tags: android, tabs

I am trying to set custom colors for my tabs in android programmatically. Unselected color - black. Selected color - white. But only the first tab remains selected because of

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

But the remaining tabs when selected do not change color. I do not know what I am missing. Here is what I have:

```
TabHost tabhost;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
tabHost = getTabHost();
.... // remaining definition of tabs go here

for(int i=0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    } 
    //tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

 } // close of oncreate() function

public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    for(int i=0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));   //inactive tabs
    }


      tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); //active tab
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line in:

```
tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); //active tab
```

Comment: no good, it still is the same. Color doesnt change for the selected tab... Even when selected, it is still black.

Comment: Actually it worked. I did it in another way. Comments from this question helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356546/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-selected-tab-in-android