# How to Highlight the TAB if there is a DATA

Tags: java, android, tabs

I have implemented a Tab host in First form and there is a 3 Tabs. For 3 Tabs i have declared a three forms.
Ex: There is a RED,GREEN and BLUE Tabs If i click on RED Tab in First form It will redirect to RED form.
Now My problem is If i append a GREEN form It should highlight the GREEN Tab in First Form.

Comment: Can you show your codes please ? ( edit your question )

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356546/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-selected-tab-in-android) an example of how to change the color of tab when it is changed using a `onTabChangeListener`.

Comment: My problem is If i update a data in GREEN form, How can i highlight the GREEN TAB in First form