# TabWidget background color change

Tags: android, xml, colors, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I want to change the background color of the TabWidget. I have a picture for the tab that I don't want to change, I only want to change the background color of that Image without replacing it with another image, here is my code.

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected color blue -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/profile"
        android:state_selected="true"/>
    <!-- When NOT selected color black -->
    <item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/profile">

    </item>
</selector>
```

For example in the following line(When is selected) to put something like..

```
<item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/profile" android:backgroundColor="#5397CB">
```

and in the NOTselected state to be black..

```
<item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@drawable/profile" android:backgroundColor="#fffff">
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099959/how-do-i-change-the-background-of-an-android-tab-widget