# OnTabChangeListener Null Pointer

Tags: android

I am attempting to create custom colors of the tabs in a TabHost.

I have impletmented `OnTabChangeListener` and the MainActivity loads up correctly. However when I click on a new tab I get a null pointer. Where is my error located? I cannot understand  what the issue is.

Here is the offending code loosely based off of [this example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-%E2%80%93-part-2)

```
@Override  
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {  
     for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
     {  
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.greygradient));  
     }
     tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt((tabHost.getCurrentTab())).setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bluegradient));
}
```

Here is the trace:

```
06-20 14:27:42.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1490): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 14:27:42.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at com.company.app.MainActivity.onTabChanged(MainActivity.java:72)
06-20 14:27:42.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.widget.TabHost.invokeOnTabChangeListener(TabHost.java:359)
06-20 14:27:42.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:344)
06-20 14:27:42.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:132)
06-20 14:27:42.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:456)
06-20 14:27:42.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-20 14:27:42.770: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have gone with the StackOverflow example: [How do I change the background of an Android tab widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099959/how-do-i-change-the-background-of-an-android-tab-widget/3936685#3936685) :-)

```
@Override  
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    setTabColor(getTabHost());
}

private void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
    for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); //unselected
    }
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF")); // selected
}
```

**The most likely reason for your NullPointer is your TabHost**, check that this is being instantiated, I assume you do it within onCreate.

If you are extending TabActivity you can just call `getTabHost();` from your Activity context.

Comment: Interesting that 45 minutes of searching on SO never brought up that answer, although i've seen similar answers...Anyways your example works, when I try and replace your colors with my drawable gradients i get the null pointer again. Are those structured wrong?

Comment: Solved it, still not sure where the syntax error was (maybe the extra set of () I have in the second line?) Thanks!