# Tab widget styles and colors

Tags: android, colors, tabs, styles, size

How to change tab widget background color? Where I could find those Style codes?

P.S. How to make text written in tabs get centered?

Comment: The below stackoverflow will help you [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3936685/1329126](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3936685/1329126/)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

save this image to any drawable folder call it footer.png

and set this as background image of your tab-widget as

```
<TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.75"
            android:background="@drawable/footer" 
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
```