# How to customize android tabs or bottom border?

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, android-tabs, android-tabactivity

I am stuck with creating a simple design using Tabs widget in Android.

Please help me to create a similar design.

[image]

Just note that , the bottom border is not at the bottom of the box and also its width is much less than the width of the box.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722654/tabwidget-current-tab-bottom-line-color

Comment: @sasikumar : please check my image , its completely different , i have already seen that link. Anyways thanks for reply.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897351/how-to-customize-android-tabs-or-background-change

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `TabLayout` then you can use [setCustomView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html#setCustomView(int)) to set custom tab.

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(pagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }
```

Checkout here for [full example](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout#add-custom-view-to-tablayout)

Comment: Still question is , will it behave like tabs , when adding custom view , like when i click on "family" tab , the border should slide down below family. Can i be able to maintain that sliding effect.