# EditText to String using Fragment

Tags: android

Like we always use **getText().toString();** to get String from ***EditText***, So why i am facing problem, earlier i was using Activity and now just switched to **Fragment**, see Log:

```
 02-19 00:17:27.508: V/strDate..... >>>(1354): android.widget.EditText{b1ecd2c0 V.ED..CL ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f080001 app:id/editTextToShowDate}
```

**Fragment**

```
@Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.android_frag, container, false);
        final EditText editTextDate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextToShowDate);
        String strDate = editTextDate.getText().toString();
        Log.v("strDate..... >>>", strDate);
        return view;
 }
```

Comment: Is your editTextDate in your Fragment layout? is it null? It is null for sure as you are calling it right after creating it. Can you check this and also post more of the log cat?

Comment: please post your logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the text from editText on button click event

```
String strDate = editTextDate.getText().toString();
```

Comment: oh my bad luck i forgot to use Button widget, anyways thanks i ticked it as useful and will accept after 12 minutes, silly mistake :(

Comment: please let me know how can i change Tab Indicator (Underline) color programmatically ? to change ActionBar background color i used setBackgroundDrawable(...)

Comment: @AbrahimNeil pls look @ https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: bro without using xml ? my mean programmatically !

Comment: Again look for the api's in the docs which can help. and search on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847416/how-to-change-tab-indicator-color-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

You should populate the following code into onStart() not onCreateView().

```
final EditText editTextDate = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editTextToShowDate);
    String strDate = editTextDate.getText().toString();
```