# Action bar indicator's color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

So ,I suppose the title says it all.

I gave my action bar a color using this code and I want to change the color of the tab indicator ,yet there seems to be no method implemented and pretty much everything I found so far ,is way too complicated for a simple default color change.

```
   actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN));
```

Can anyone guide me through this thing ,please?

My best guess is that I have to change the default color (It's some lightish blue) ,to whatever I need, but I have no clue where the XML file for this specific thing is.

Any other solution is highly appreciated ,but please don't send me "Android Action Bar  Style Generator" ,I really hate so called generated things and stuff like this.I want to do everything as low level as possible.

If any other information is needed ,leave a comment, I will respond asap.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847416/how-to-change-tab-indicator-color-programmatically

Comment: Read everything I wrote sir.Thanks for the answer anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the indicator color use [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/tab_indicator_holo.xml)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_holo" />
<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_holo" />
<!-- Pressed -->
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />
</selector>
```

Simply change the drawable and set it to what you like. Note that those are [9 patch drawable](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/tab_selected_holo.9.png). you can also use [ColorFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html) to change the color of them programmatically.

Comment: Gonna be trying this ,although I think I found a smoother way -gonna test this first.

Comment: I am not sure wether it is what I was looking for or not and it's because I did not test it ,although, a kind guy gave me a link to a method that is not deprecated ,as is what I was using before and I am pretty sure what you wrote applys for the non-deprecated method ,not for what I was using. Anyways,gonna give the link here, in the comment and confirm your answer as correct ,as it is explained detailed and I pretty much understood what's there.Cheers! The link: http://maxalley.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/android-creating-a-tab-layout-with-fragmenttabhost-and-fragments/